# Android ImageView how to fit left-bottom such as setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_END);, but not fit right-bottom

Tags: android, imageview, scale

I use below code to set ImageView's ScaleType:

```
iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_END);
```

It will fit right-bottom.
But I want to make picture fit left-bottom.
How can I do it?

Comment: This maybe : `LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
iv.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the imageview's adjust view bound to true and then set the align bottom parent and align left parent to true. hope that works :)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
imageView.setBaselineAlignBottom(true);
```

Works for `API_LEVEL` >= 11.